# Heroku Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, webpack, deployment

Good afternoon, I want to deploy my project on heroku, but it doesn't work. The error with the logs is understandable, but why it happens to me is not clear. The error lies in the fact that heroku cannot find index.html in the dist, although the dist is created locally and the index is also in it.

I am attaching a link to the [repository](https://github.com/belichenk0andreyka/Monefy), [screenshot of logs of Heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcwL2.png) and [screen of dist folder in project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDBYQ.png) I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the command `yarn build` of the `/client` folden in your Heroku deployment process. Or, remove the `dist` folder from your `.gitignore` file, so the final build stays on the repository.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, it works, but I think it's not quite the right solution, is it?

Comment: The right solution is to add the build script to your deployment process

Comment: Please tell me how to do it

Comment: Can you give me some links where I can find out how to do this

Comment: Just add this `"build": "cd client && npm run build",` to the scripts on your `package.json` as Heroku now runs the `build` script automatically on deploys.

Link here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1557

Comment: I will try this solution, thank you very much